# How to open the gallery and select an image straight to adobe photo editor via a click on the image?

Tags: adobecreativesdk, creative-cloud

I'm using sdk *creativecloud* (photo editor). I'm trying to open the gallery and select it, the more I do not want her va for a imageView. I want my app to be similiar to the *[aviary](http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aviary.android.feather&hl=en)* app (which also and photo editor)

Question: When it will access the gallery User select an image? Is that redirected to direct carriage sdk editor?

Answer (score 0):

```
fab_explore = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);

    fab_explore.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent pickIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            pickIntent.setType("image/*");
            Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(pickIntent,"Pick Picture");
            startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, CAPTURE_LOCAL_PHOTO_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    });
```

now on the activity result call these to access the path to pass the photoeditor

```
 if (requestCode == CAPTURE_LOCAL_PHOTO_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Uri imageUri = data.getData();


            Intent imageEditorIntent = new AdobeImageIntent.Builder(this)
                    .setData(imageUri)
                    .build();

            startActivityForResult(imageEditorIntent, 1);


        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            Log.i("MainActivity", "onActivityResult: failed to get image");

        } else {
        }
```